# What to do when git clone is stuck at the compressing phase?

Tags: git, repository, clone

I'm cloning a git repository to my computer. However, it is stuck for more than an hour at the following step:

```
Cloning into <the_repository>...
remote: Counting objects: 5490, done.
remote: Compressing objects:  26% (987/3732)
```

After waiting for more than an hour, it didn't move on to the next object. I heard from the owner of the repository that this is possibly a gigantic file that I don't need. Is there a possibility to skip a single file? Or are there other solutions for my problem?. I've restarted the cloning process a few times, but it didn't help. I'm quite new to using git.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is caused by the transfer protocol restriction between remote and local. Another protocol works perhaps.

As listed in git documents, the following protocols you can give a try.

- ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
- git://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
- http[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
- ftp[s]://host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/
- rsync://host.xz/path/to/repo.git/
- [user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/