# git fetch stuck after compressing object

Tags: git, ubuntu-server

Is there anyone ever experienced similar situation like mine?

This been happening since several days, git fetch and git pull operation just stuck on

"Compressing Objects ...."

This happens on ubuntu server,

Server Info :
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
4GB RAM , 50GB Storage

[image: Git fetch stuck image]

Have i tried to reboot the system ? yes i have tried that

Also tried :

- to do a fresh clone, but apparently git clone also impacted.
- tried to do `git gc prune` and git reflog command, still no result

SSH access to git with ssh -T git@github.com is also running with no problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do when git clone is stuck at the compressing phase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038958/what-to-do-when-git-clone-is-stuck-at-the-compressing-phase)

Comment: No i already tried to move into https, ssh over https, none of them work, still stuck at that phase

Comment: It also sometimes stuck while counting objects also